# How to setup macOS server capable of handling large number of small files?

Tags: macos, mac, smb, file-server, iscsi

I'm trying to setup my Mac mini as a file server so that I can share it with my MacBook Pro. I'll be designating a folder in my Mac mini that both computers can easily write and read from.

I first tried to use the built-in File Sharing option in macOS, which uses the SMB protocol. This works perfectly fine with large files, actually surprisingly fast, but with hundreds/thousands of small files is extremely slow, to the point of being unusable for my needs. After some research, this seems to be the expected behavior for this protocol.

Is there any other protocol I could use to setup my server that can handle a large number of small files efficiently? iSCSI has come up in my searches, but it doesn't seem very straightforward to setup on Mac.

I'm not looking for syncing solutions like iCloud Drive, Resilio Sync, etc. I want a local server setup that I can directly access files from.

Comment: How do you define "large number of small files"? NFS might be what you are looking for. You might need to tune it for small files. If you only want to download the files, not upload them, HTTP could be the way to go. It is hard to say, because you only define your needs to be incompatible with SMB

Comment: @mashuptwice In my case, "large number of small files" means multiple root folders (~200), containing on average 500 items, and each item averaging 20kb in size. And as I mentioned on my post, I need to read and write. Are there any links you can point me to for setting up NFS?

Comment: @mashuptwice NFS was 100% the way to go. I was able to set it up very easily with this tool: https://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html. Add your comment as an answer if you like, and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS should be capable to do that easily and is supported by most systems. I had very good results with it in both local networks and tunneled over the internet with big, small and many files.

While I don't know about MacOS, it is very easy to set up on linux.

Feel free to edit my answer with setup instructions for MacOS.

Comment: “While I don't know about MacOS, it is very easy to set up on linux.” Then why share this non-macOS answer on a question that is focused on macOS? It will not help the original poster. Additionally, the question is effectively off-topic since it is asking for a tutorial on how to do this. Your first paragraph is good as a comment but this should not be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 from my understanding the question was about a suggestion for a protocol which can handle a great amount of small files, not a tutorial on how to setup a specific software or service and not about recommending a specific software. "It will not help the original poster" I've added this answer because said original poster suggested that I should do so, as it solved the issue for him. NFS is not platform specific and my answer seems to satisfy all requirements in this case.

Comment: If you believe your answer is correct the original poster recommends using [NFSManager](https://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html) in [their comment in response to your NFS suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/1719928/how-to-setup-macos-server-capable-of-handling-large-number-of-small-files/1719942?noredirect=1#comment2655090_1719928). Your answer should at least mention NFSManager right away and the Linux stuff _might_ stay but would not really be useful for someone looking for a macOS solution.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I will not recommend a software which I could not test. Also there are other ways of setting up NFS on macos. I've removed the paragraph about linux, feel free to point out further things that in your opinion invalidate the answer.